# can't show the thumbnail from youtube?

Tags: android, image, youtube, thumbnails, playlist

this app should show thumbnail , title, and the duration of each video in the playlist selected , but   thumbnail remain white
the application works but It don't show the thumbnail of the video in the playlist

how can I do ? you have any solution?

THIS IS MY CODE

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

ImageView mainThumb;
TextView mainTitle;
TextView mainTime;
LinearLayout videos;
ArrayList<String> links;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.videos);

    new ParseVideoDataTask().execute();
    mainThumb = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.mainThumb);
    mainTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mainTitle);
    mainTime = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mainTime);
    videos = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.videos);

}

private class ParseVideoDataTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    int count = 0;

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        URL jsonURL;
        URLConnection jc;
        links = new ArrayList<String>();
        try {
            jsonURL = new URL("http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/" +
                    "PL-7t9DoIELCRF7F7bZvvBwO1yvHRFsJiu" +  
                "?v=2&alt=jsonc");
            //PL_VGbflD64WSR1MBcpWlNwsY0lRNVuJ3r
             jc = jsonURL.openConnection(); 
             InputStream is = jc.getInputStream(); 
            String jsonTxt = IOUtils.toString(is);
             JSONObject jj = new JSONObject(jsonTxt); 
             JSONObject jdata = jj.getJSONObject("data"); 
             JSONArray aitems = jdata.getJSONArray("items"); 
             for (int i=0;i<aitems.length();i++) {
                 JSONObject item = aitems.getJSONObject(i); 
                 JSONObject video = item.getJSONObject("video"); 
                 String title = video.getString("title");
                 JSONObject player = video.getJSONObject("player");
                 String link = player.getString("default");
                 String length = video.getString("duration");
                 JSONObject thumbnail = video.getJSONObject("thumbnail"); 
                 String thumbnailUrl = thumbnail.getString("hqDefault");
                 String[] deets = new String[4];
                 deets[0] = title;
                 deets[1] = thumbnailUrl;
                 deets[2] = length;
                 links.add(link);
                 publishProgress(deets);
             }
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }       
        return null;
    }       

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(final String... deets) {
        count++;
        if (count == 1) {
            MainActivity.setImageFromUrl(deets[1], mainThumb, MainActivity.this);
            mainTitle.setText(deets[0]);
            mainTime.setText(formatLength(deets[2]));
            mainThumb.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(links.get(1)));
                    startActivity(i);
                }
            });
        } else {
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)MainActivity.this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View video = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.video, null);
            ImageView thumb = (ImageView) video.findViewById(R.id.thumb);
            TextView title = (TextView) video.findViewById(R.id.title);
            TextView time = (TextView) video.findViewById(R.id.time);
            MainActivity.setImageFromUrl(deets[1], thumb, MainActivity.this);
            title.setText(deets[0]);
            time.setText(formatLength(deets[2]));
            video.setPadding(20, 20, 20, 20);
            videos.addView(video);
            video.setId(count-1);
            video.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(links.get(v.getId())));
                    startActivity(i);
                }
            });
        }
    }
}

private CharSequence formatLength(String secs) {
    int secsIn = Integer.parseInt(secs);
    int hours = secsIn / 3600,
            remainder = secsIn % 3600,
            minutes = remainder / 60,
            seconds = remainder % 60;

            return ((minutes < 10 ? "0" : "") + minutes
            + ":" + (seconds< 10 ? "0" : "") + seconds );
}



public static void setImageFromUrl(String string, ImageView mainThumb2,
        MainActivity mainActivity) {

}



@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    for (int i=0;i<videos.getChildCount();i++) {
        View v = videos.getChildAt(i);
        if (v instanceof ImageView) {
            ImageView iv = (ImageView) v;           
            ((BitmapDrawable)iv.getDrawable()).getBitmap().recycle();   
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: I don't have an answer for you yet, but I do recommend you use an Http library like Retrofit http://square.github.io/retrofit/, it might make your life a lot easier in dealing with Http endpoints. :)

Answer (score 0):

Use [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) to set the image url like so:

```
Picasso.withContext(this).load(thumbnailUrl).into(myImageView);
```

To do this you'll need to return the JSON object in the doInBackground method, or use something like Retrofit (as I mentioned in the comment above) to get a nice POJO and return that. Then in the postExecute you can use the thumbnail url in the JSON (or POJO) and set it using Picasso above. Picasso will take care of downloading and caching the image for you and loading it into the image view.

Comment: So you'll need to implement onPostExecute in your AsyncTask. Instead of returning null from doInBackground, you will return the JSON object (or POJO if using Retrofit/etc). Then once in onPostExecute you can load the image via Picasso.

Comment: I'm sorry but I did not understand much can you show me with a line of sample code? please